# why is there a dot in my path before the parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a route like this -

```
match "/related/:id", :to  => "sentances#related"
```

and in my sentance controlller an action like this  -

```
def related
    @sentance = Sentance.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then I have a link in my view like this -

```
   <td><%= link_to 'related', related_path(sentance) %></td>
```

The link is rendering as - http://my-site.local/related.1

I expected it to be  - http://my-site.local/related/1

Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your `rake routes` you'll see that your `match` line didn't create any path helpers.  You need to add `:as => :related` if you want to use something like `related_path`